# Showing a set is compact

Tags: general-topology

I need help with the question 7/b part in the image below. About the point 0, any open set contains points of the other non zero set , except for finitely many points. But then, I am facing difficulty in adjoining the rest of the open covers and their form.
[image: the problem]

Comment: are you allowing the use of the equivalence, in $\Bbb R$, of the concepts of "compact" and "closed and bounded"?

Comment: If I were doing this problem, I'd do it out of order: find all limit points (c), show that they're all contained in $S$ (a), and use Heine-Borel to conclude (b).

Comment: BUt the tricky part there is that sure you can find all the limit points heuristically, but how to prove that a some real number *not* in your purported set of limit points (say $e^{-10}$ as an example that does not give away the answer by telling what the limit points are) is not a limit point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $S$ by open sets of the reals. Let $U_0 \in \mathcal{U}$ be such that $0 \in U_0$ and find $r>0$ such that $(-r,r) \subseteq U_0$. Then, setting $M= \frac{2}{r}$ we find that all points $x(n,m) = \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$ with $n,m > M$ already obey $x < r$ and so $x \in U_0$, so we only need to take care of the points $x(n,m)$ with $n \le M$ or $m \le M$ (by symmetry we only need to consider the $n \le M$ case, as $x(n,m)=x(m,n)$).

Now, for $n \le M$ we note that $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n} \in S$ and so $\frac{1}{n}$ must be covered by some $U_n \in \mathcal{U}$ as well. As $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m} \to \frac{1}{n}$ as $m \to \infty$, all but finitely many $x(n,m)$, $x(n,m) \in U_n$.

So the final finite subcover consists of $U_0$, the finitely many $U_n$ for $n \le M$ and some finitely many $U_x$ for those $x$ that are the (finite times finitely many) not-yet-covered points for the aforementioned finitely many ones.

Comment: @ravenchaser I forgot to halve the $r$, so I edited my answer. Now it is fully correct I believe. In essence your idea works, but you have to write it down properly.

Comment: Thank you.. this is the kind of approach is was thinking since yesterday. So, aside from the open set around 0, there can be atmost mn elements and hence, there are at most mn + 1 open sets that cover our set S, am I right ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}$ though...

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης Verum est.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Looks correct now, +1!

Answer (score 2):

You can show sequencial compactness which in a metric space like $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to compactness. If you have $s_i=\frac{1}{m_i}+\frac{1}{n_i}$ then there are 3 cases:

1) assume $m_i,n_i$ are bounded and by the pigeonhole principle you can prove that there exists a $k$ such that $s_k$ appears infinitelly many times. Pick this subsequence then.

2) assume WLOG $m_i$ is bounded and $n_i$ is not. Take an infinite increasing subsequence of $n_i$ and use pigeonhole principle again to conclude the existence of infinite values $s_i=\frac{1}{m_k}+\frac{1}{n_i}$ where $m_k$ is constant and $n_i$ is increasing. This subsequence converges to $\frac{1}{m_k}$

3) assume $m_i,n_i$ are both unbounded. Take any infinite increasing sequence $n_i$ and then either the corresponding $m_i$ form an unbounded sequence from which you can then pick an increasing $m_j$ subsequence and take $s_j=\frac{1}{m_j}+\frac{1}{n_j}$ with $\lim_{j\to\infty}n_j=0$ or the corresponding values $m_i$ form a finite set and you can procceed as in 2).

Answer (score 1):

Consider subset $P = \{(\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n} | n, m \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{(0, 0)\}$ of plane. $P$ is compact: any convergent sequence convergence in both coordinates, and convergent sequence with elements $\{\frac{1}{n}\} \cup \{0\}$ is either eventually constant, or converges to $0$, so it converges to element from $\{\frac{1}{n}\}\cup \{0\}$.

Now, let us take function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x, y) = x + y$. Then $f$ is continuous and $S = f(P)$. And continuous image of a compact is a compact.